# How to stop a thread in java while it is in a waiting state?

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose I have one thread named `T1` which is holding the lock while other threads `T2`, `T3`, `T4` are waiting for the lock. Now, I want to stop thread `T2`, but the other threads `T3`, `T4` should be still waiting. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Call interrupt() and do try/catch around wait() for InterruptedException

Comment: Check out [`ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#lockInterruptibly--).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `interrupt()` method from the `Thread Class` something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread t = new Thread(someTask());
    t.start();     
    Thread.sleep(3_000);    
    t.interrupt();  
    t.join(1_000); 
}
private static Runnable someTask() {
    return () -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(i);     
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1_000);  
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;                
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is utilize `T2.interrupt()`. Interrupt will wake up the respective thread and throw an `InterruptionException` that the thread must handle. From here, you can end the thread. Lets look at a brief example of `T2`'s possible `Runnable`'s `run()` method below.

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            doNonBlockingWork(); // Random code logic
            doBlockingWork(); // Where the thread will attempt to get and wait for the lock
            doMoreCode(); // Will never get here if interrupt is called while waiting for lock above
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // Maintain Interrupt Status
            break; // Finish
        }
    }
}
```

If another thread, lets say the `main` thread executes the following code,

```
public void killSpecificThread() {
    doMyLogic();
    startThreads(); // All the threads begin
    T2.interrupt();
    doMoreLogic();
}
```

`T2` will wake up (this works the same as well if it was awake, just no wake up step) and immediately be thrown an `InterruptionException`. Because of our try catch above, we are able to handle it by finishing the `run()` method.